# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" in Python

Tags: python

I am making a program for autotry to join a meeting (because it is full) and i ran into the error:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
import pyautogui as pt
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
def join():
    posjoin = pt.locateOnScreen('join.png', confidence=.6)
    x=posjoin[0]
    y=posjoin[1]
    pt.moveTo(x+20,y+5)
    pt.click()

def enterid():
    posid = pt.locateOnScreen('id.png', confidence=.6)
    x=posid[0]
    y=posid[1]
    pt.moveTo(x+20,y+5)
    pt.click()
    pt.typewrite('meetingid')
    pt.moveRel(929-780,459-251)
    pt.click()

def passcode():
    pospass = pt.locateOnScreen('pass.png', confidence=.6)
    x=pospass[0]
    y=pospass[1]
    pt.moveTo(x+20,y+5)
    pt.click()
    pt.typewrite('meetingpassword')
    pt.moveRel(826-686,498-291)
    pt.click()

def choose():
    poscho = pt.locateOnScreen('video.png', confidence=.6)
    x=poscho[0]
    y=poscho[1]
    pt.moveTo(x+20,y+5)
    pt.click()

def capacity():
    poscap = pt.locateOnScreen('capacity.png', confidence=.6)
    x=poscap[0]
    y=poscap[1]
    pt.moveTo(x+316,y+266)
    pt.click()

a = 1 
while a < 3:
    join()
    sleep(1)
    enterid()
    sleep(1.5)
    passcode()
    sleep(3.5)
    choose()
    sleep(3.5)
    capacity()
    a += 1
```

And the error is :

```
  File "e:\projects\zoom oto\zoommain.py", line 49, in <module>
    enterid()
  File "e:\projects\zoom oto\zoommain.py", line 13, in enterid
    x=posid[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

What i don't understand is when i use the code like this it works perfectly, and it doesn't give any error

```
import pyautogui as pt
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
def join():
    posjoin = pt.locateOnScreen('join.png', confidence=.6)
    x=posjoin[0]
    y=posjoin[1]
    pt.moveTo(x+20,y+5)
    pt.click()

def enterid():
    posid = pt.locateOnScreen('id.png', confidence=.6)
    x=posid[0]
    y=posid[1]
    pt.moveTo(x+20,y+5)
    pt.click()
    pt.typewrite('meetingid')
    pt.moveRel(929-780,459-251)
    pt.click()

def passcode():
    pospass = pt.locateOnScreen('pass.png', confidence=.6)
    x=pospass[0]
    y=pospass[1]
    pt.moveTo(x+20,y+5)
    pt.click()
    pt.typewrite('meetingpassword')
    pt.moveRel(826-686,498-291)
    pt.click()

def choose():
    poscho = pt.locateOnScreen('video.png', confidence=.6)
    x=poscho[0]
    y=poscho[1]
    pt.moveTo(x+20,y+5)
    pt.click()

def capacity():
    poscap = pt.locateOnScreen('capacity.png', confidence=.6)
    x=poscap[0]
    y=poscap[1]
    pt.moveTo(x+316,y+266)
    pt.click()

join()
```

I would be very happy if someone helps.

Comment: Obviously here `pt.locateOnScreen('id.png', confidence=.6)` returns None. Maybe it can't find id.png?

Comment: if you are sure that this fuction works enterid() originally, try to increase the sleep time, because as @EgorWexler mentioned that, it is returning None.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem i changed the confidence to 0.4 and it worked.

Comment: Yeah the problem was on enterid() but i tried to run join() only thank you